# Booting stops with systemd-fstab-generator "but it is not a device"

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd

Since a few my arch (upgraded to latest packages today) is not booting properly.

```
[    0.658449] nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
[    0.851921] nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[    0.857780]  nvme0n1: p1 p2
[    9.541817] systemd-fstab-generator[440]: Checking was requested for "/dev/nvme0n1p1", but it is not a device.
```

It stops at the rescue console. I can log in and mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 manually and then continue to boot normally.

```
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot
```

I tried adressing the device with `UUID` and `PARTUUID` with the same error. This is really annoying. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

My fstab looks like this:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1              /boot   vfat    rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 2
/dev/mapper/root            /               ext4         defaults        0 1
/dev/mapper/tmp             /tmp            tmpfs        defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/swap            none            swap         sw              0 0
```

Additional information:

```
$ ls -l /dev/nvme0n1p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1  3. Mär 07:49 /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

```
$ file /dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1: block special (259/1)
```

```
$ file -s /dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 32, heads 64, hidden sectors 2048, sectors 1046529 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 1024, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x1560e429, unlabeled
```

Comment: Try to use UUID instead?

Comment: @TomYan Forgot to add I already tried `UUID` and `PARTUUID`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski
`brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1  3. Mär 07:49 /dev/nvme0n1p1`
and
`/dev/nvme0n1p1: block special (259/1)`
and
`/dev/nvme0n1p1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 32, heads 64, hidden sectors 2048, sectors 1046529 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 1024, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x1560e429, unlabeled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my fstab from

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1              /boot   vfat    rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 2
/dev/mapper/root            /               ext4         defaults        0 1
/dev/mapper/tmp             /tmp            tmpfs        defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/swap            none            swap         sw              0 0
```

to

```
# nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1              /boot   vfat    rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 2
/dev/mapper/root            /               ext4         defaults        0 1
/dev/mapper/tmp             /tmp            tmpfs        defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/swap            none            swap         sw              0 0
```

and now it works again.

I don't get it.